# Which is the common name of Mind Flayers?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, forgotten-realms

Would the average person in the Forgotten Realms call Mind Flayers "Mind Flayers" or "Illithid?"

Comment: “Ahhh sweet Pelor no!”

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### The average person living on the surface almost certainly knows them as Mind Flayers, if they know them at all

*Dragon #281* includes the article "By Any Other Name: Races of the Underdark", about the naming conventions of the various races that live in the Underdark, which explains that in their native telepathic communication mind flayers are identified by a sort of thought-image or pattern, but that:

> ... when members of the other races of the Underdark have need to refer to a particular illithid, they usually try to translate his identifying thought-image into the trade tongue of Undercommon.

This is accompanied by a couple of tables which suggest that the word "illithid" itself is formed from the two Undercommon words "illi", meaning "mind", and "thid", meaning "flayer/ruler" - so illithid is literally just the Undercommon word meaning "mind flayer".

As a little bonus, many of the specific translated words in these tables form parts of the names of other notable monsters in the illithid family. From them, we can see that "[ulitharid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ulitharid)" means "noble devourer", "[alhoon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/alhoon)" means "dead abomination/outsider", "[urophion](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Urophion)" means "servant/slave/thrall black/dark/darkness", and the -thelid part of "[neothelid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/neothelid)" means "conqueror/eater".

Undercommon is a rare language on the surface, and mind flayers themselves are even rarer; it seems very unlikely that the term "illithid" would have made its way into other languages as a loanword, given the language would be very rarely encountered and the term very rarely useful. Undercommon speakers who had occasion to tell surface-dwellers about the illithid would presumably have just directly translated to "mind flayer" to preserve the meaning.

Comment: If a common man knew anything at all about a Mind Flayer it likely would be short lived as he would probably have been lunch or never seen again.