# Do Illithid tadpoles have a specific name?

Tags: monsters, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, terminology

So Illithids trigger ceremorphosis by inserting a tadpole into a subdued creature (lovely), but do the tadpoles have a name other than tadpoles?

As far as I can see my 5th edition books only use the word tadpoles, which makes me think they don't have a specific name, but I am curious in case anyone else is aware of anything from previous editions or elsewhere (or has found something in the 5e content that I have just missed).

Comment: How is "Illithid tadpole" or "Mindflayer tadpole" not specific enough? Are you looking for a term exclusive to Illithid tadpoles, such as "kittens" or "puppies"?

Comment: @PixelMaster For example mindflayer is the 'common' term, but Illithid is the real term. I am wondering if there is a similar thing for these tadpoles. Plus I really don't like the word tadpole, the more I say it the less it means. And yes, something that just refers to these creatures unambiguously.

Comment: [Remember that "Illithid" is just "mind flayer" in Undercommon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/148658/35259)

Comment: Of course they have names. That sucker is 24 of 21... Or is that 22 of 21? They all look alike

Comment: Nice try Larian, we've already seen the tooltips `[TADPOLE POWER]`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### *Illithid tadpole* is used when it may not be clear from context that mind flayer young are being described.

Otherwise, just “tadpole" seems to be the consistently used term.

From the *AD&D 2nd Edition Monstrous Manual* (pg. 251):

> Mind flayers live about 125 years. They are warm-blooded amphibians, and spend the first 10 years of life as **tadpoles**, swimming in the elder-brain pool until they either die (which most do) or grow into adult illithids. On an irregular basis, adult illithids feed brains to the **tadpoles**, which do not molest the elder-brain. Illithids are hermaphroditic; each can produce one **tadpole** twice in its life.

From the 3.5e *Monster Manual V*, concerning the Madcrafters of Thoon, a race of creatures that was once Illithid (pg. 121-122):

> Though the madcrafters of Thoon are no longer mind
> flayers, they have a similar life cycle. The asexual madcrafters
> give birth to thousands of **tadpoles** in a spawning pool deep
> within the nautiloid vessel (not the same pool the Thoon elder
> brain lives in). The **tadpoles** feast on each other in a frenzy
> of cannibalism punctuated by long periods of group torpor. [...]
>
> Like a traditional mind flayer elder brain, a Thoon elder brain
> subsists on **tadpolelike** immature mind flayers.

Additionally, the 3.5e book *Lords of Madness* contains *45 occurrences* of **tadpole** and its various forms. I won't reproduce all of them here.

From the 4e *Monster Manual* (pg. 189):

> A mind flayer begins life as a small,
> tentacled, **tadpolelike** parasite that invades the
> skull of a helpless humanoid victim, devours its
> brain, and then subverts the body to its own use.

In addition to the [ceremorphosis](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/monster-lore#TheImportanceofBrains) mentioned  in *Volo's Guide to Monsters*, we have a few more references in 5e material.

From the description of the [Neothelid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/vgtm/bestiary#Neothelid) (VGtM, pg. 181):

> On rare occasions, an illithid colony collapses, typically after an external assault, and the elder brain is killed. When that happens, the colony’s **tadpoles** are suddenly freed from their fate. They no longer serve as food, and in turn are no longer fed by their caretakers. Driven by hunger, they turn to devouring one another. Only one **tadpole** survives out of the thousands in the colony’s pool, and it emerges as a neothelid.

From [*Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdotmm/dungeon-denizens#Ulitharid):

> Very rarely, an **illithid tadpole** transforms an individual into an ulitharid rather than an ordinary mind flayer.

From [*Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wdh/spring-madness#AreasoftheLair):

> Qrr’zarq comes from a colony of mind flayers in Undermountain that wants to implant Xanathar with an **illithid tadpole** and, through a magical process called ceremorph­osis, turn the beholder into a thrall. Qrr’zarq is waiting for an opportunity to implant the **tadpole** while Xanathar is alone and asleep.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official name for a mindflayer tadpole. But sticking with known Undercommon words, I like:

"ilsenarint" - (Brain Taster)

This is from the Undercommon words *ilsen* (brain) and *arint* (taster).<sup>1</sup> These Undercommon words are often used to label illithids, assigning them "names" of a sort in that tongue, so properly "Ilsenarint" might be what some non-illithid names a particular illithid they’ve encountered. (Illithids themselves communicate telepathically and so have purely telepathic names.) But it's a good choice for naming the tadpoles.

1. <sub>Owen K. C. Stephens, "By Any Other Name: Races of the Underdark", *Dragon* magazine, vol. 281, March 2001. **Note:** This issue was published by Wizards of the Coast; Paizo didn't take over publication of *Dragon* until 2002.</sub>

Comment: To clarify is “ilsenarint” an officially used compound of “ilsen” and “arint” from some canonical media, or are you making a conjecture  that those two words would be compounded to describe mind flayers?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know if this is any way a true answer, but I do love it!

Comment: @ThomasMarkov “ilsen-” and “-arint” are suggested as entries in a scheme to randomly generate illithid names in Undercommon by rolling once or twice on a prefix table and then rolling once or twice on a suffix table. “Ilsenarint” would be the result for rolling 1-2 on a d6, 4 on a d12, and 1 on another d12 under this system, and does mean “brain taster.” There is no suggestion that it would be used for the tadpoles; the idea in the article is rather to use it as a non-illithid’s name for an illithid.

Comment: @SeriousBri It’s true that these are suggested as Undercommon words to use to label illithids, but it’s meant as a way to produce names for individual illithids, rather than an official name for the tadpoles. Still, it’s a really good suggestion.

Comment: There are limited official undercommon words. This is a new compound presented as a suggestion for the most likely term in undercommon for the tadpoles. I like it so much I’m going to include it in anything I release about mindflayers on DMs guild.