# Is there any way for a Mind Flayer to go back to their original human(oid) form?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, forgotten-realms

According to 5e lore, the [Mind Flayer / Illithid lore](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Mind_flayer) reproduces via [ceremorphosis](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Ceremorphosis): a tiny illithid-creature eats its way into the (sentient) target's brain, forcing transformation to occur some time later.

Under what conditions is this either preventable &/or entirely reversible (*Regeneration* or *Mind Protection* rings, restorative / regenerative spells, back-up clones, polymorphs... anything at all)? Is there, once again, nothing lower level than *Wish* to solve this?

This is valuable for DMing & story-construction: many transformed *illithids* might / would / could miss their previous existence (such as an Illithid [Arcanist](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mind-flayer-arcanist) and [mindwitness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/mindwitness).) If such a reversal is possible, it would be fine to know.

Comment: In [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/171841/62294) I outline many sources from many editions where Illithids are described. These may help find an answer here.

Comment: Is the lore you cite from 5e or from general lore? Would you prefer this to be about dungeons and dragons lore in general and not 5e specific?

Comment: @NautArch i prefer 5e, but any information on illithid aberration returning from their mutation-transformation would be useful at this point.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Once a humanoid has fully transformed into a mind flayer, the original humanoid is dead and their body is destroyed.

In the AD&D 2e sourcbeook *Monstrous Arcana: The Illithiad*, p.11, asserts that most normal means are ineffective at restoring their original form:

> Ceremorphosis completely replaces the original tissue of the victim with illithid tissue; when the transformation is complete, the original victim is dead. *Cure disease*, *remove curse*, *raise dead*, *restoration*, *resurrection*, and / or similar spells cannot reverse this process.

D&D 3e's *Lords of Madness*, p. 63, states:

> Spells such as *cure disease* and *remove curse* have no effect; **only a *heal* spell can save a victim undergoing ceremorphosis.**
>
> In most cases, the only way to guarantee the tadpole is slain is to crush or incinerate the victim's head. At that point, *resurrection*, *true resurrection*, or *raise dead* come into play.

In other words, while you can stop the transformation before it completes using a *heal* spell (this also works against other parasitic creatures like the Spawn of Kyuss), once the transformation is completed, the original humanoid is dead and their original body is destroyed; none of the original body remains.

*The Illithiad* and *Lords of Madness* don't go into any futher detail, but it stands to reason that anything which can resurrect someone without the original body might work. It's not explicitly stated, but *true resurrection* or *clone* may allow this. *Wish* and *miracle* can traditionally do just about anything, as can Divine Intervention.

A Ring of Mind Shielding (5e DMG p. 191) absorbs your soul whenever you die while wearing it. Since the process of becoming a mind flayer essentially just kills you and destroys your body, this would let your soul survive within the ring, but restoring your original body would be its own challenge.

A substance known as *laethen* allows a mind flayer to retain some of their original memories. It's described in *Monstrous Arcana: Dawn of the Overmind*, p.56. Their body becomes that of a mind flayer, but their original mind is retained. However, they need to take the substance before being transformed, and it only works 40% of the time. You could probably *polymorph* them back into their original form somehow.

A mind flayer mental illness known as *partialism* can occur, where part of the original memory is retained, but it's usually only a small amount.

Comment: Deep D&D lore, good stuff here. Story then: "*expecting illithid invasion, a wizard has flesh of various friends [enchanted & preserved](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Gentle%20Repose#content). Later, his brood become [rebel flayers](https://jsigvard.com/dnd/monster.php?m=Mind%20Flayer%20Arcanist) - and one makes 13th lvl, so they all [clone up](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Clone#content) and self-suicide-slaughter*". These 'renewed humanoids' are *really messed up* - having been aliens with no souls for quite a while.

Comment: @TimofTime If you're DMing, you can always just declare "sure, it works that way". Canon is interesting but the DM is allowed to invent their own systems.

Comment: So, what happens canon-wise with a clone made from pre-illithid flesh? Would such a humanoid body remain catatonic? Beyond insane? Just an empty shell of a body? I would love to know, t.b.h.

Comment: @TimofTime _The Illithiad_ considers that ceremorphosis kills the original creature. A clone produced later, if it could be done, would just be an inert human body which you can _raise dead_ to bring back the original human with none of the mind flayer's memories. However, the DM doesn't have to follow the suggestion in the Illithiad.

Comment: In your first quote, is it supposed to read "complete" or was that a typo of "complete**ly**"?

Answer (score 3):

*Clone* would work if it is completed before ceremorphosis, at which point the original creature dies and the clone activates.  *True Resurrection* would work afterwards, since this is a case where the original body has been destroyed.

Either of these spells would restore the original creature to life, but neither would affect the illithid itself.

Comment: Thanks! This is brilliant. There are a few 'soul' type questions, of course. Example, if the illithid doesn't use the soul, a Reincarnation cast (on a pre-harvested part) would make the original person that could meet the illithid that stole their body.